# How to get reading pane reference from VSTO add-in?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

How do you get a reference to a Reading Pane in Outlook? And how do you add an event handler to be notified with the content of the reading pane changes?

As far as I can see, Oulook doesn't consider Reading Pane as an Inspector. When ThisAddIn_Startup is fired, Application.Inspectors.Count is 0, InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler also doesn't get fired.

All I want to know is when the message is loaded in the Reading Pane and get a reference to that message (i.e. sender's email address).

Seems like a simple task, but I can't find a single example on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "ReadingPane" do you mean the pane in the main outlook window that displays the currently selected outlook message?

If so, I don't believe you access the pane directly, instead you query for the active folder and the selected message within that folder and then operate on the message directly.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, the selected message is not always the message in the reading pane. 
If you are manipulating context menus, `ActiveExplorer()`.Selection will contain the item the the context menu is acting on, instead of the item selected in the reading pane.